# Other options than burning an ISO to disk prior to installation?

Tags: linux, iso-image

When installing linux must you always burn the ISO image to disc pior to installation?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are actually asking. Are you asking if Linux installers need to be installed from a CD?

Comment: Hi Dima! Your questions on Super User generally lack formatting and are not clear. Please invest a little more time to 1) properly format them, 2) do your research before and 3) ask a specific question. Also check out [ask].

Comment: what are the purpose behind this? explain your issue which you are facing?

Comment: If you want to install Linux from a disk, the OS has to be on the disk (AKA, burn it on). It isn't going to magically appear once you pop in the CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly not.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD - Here is a list of alternate installation procedures for Ubuntu, with links to guides.

Comment: Also, when installing on VM software you can usually directly load the .iso file and have it show as if it were a disc loaded into a drive.

Comment: Please explain the downvote (not directed at Melikoth, you just happen to be the above comment :-) ). This is encouraged to show the poster (me in this case) what could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Burning an ISO image using [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) on Windows or other alternative software is the recommended way of doing it. You can certainly install Linux from other media such as USB, PXE boot, or by loading the ISO from an existing harddrive partition.